# Can Angular cli display two component at the same time where the first contain the list of item and another the overview of the item selected?

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v8

i want to know if it is possible to set-up with angular cli two component in one view , where the first component display the list of whole items and the second the overview of the item selected from the list (first component) ? for exemple : in the first component(List) we have all books in the store and when you click on one of the book , at the left of the List , you can see the details(price, edition's year ....) of the element(book) ? thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: sure this is possible and pretty basic angular functionality

Comment: What you're describing can't be done *automatically* with the cli. Create your components with the cli and then arrange them as you like in code.